# Getting error while using custom activities in an Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I am getting an error when running a custom activity in Azure Data Factory. 
 The error is:

> Job encountered scheduling error. Code: BlobDownloadMiscError
>   Category: ServerError Message: Miscellaneous error encountered while
>   downloading one of the specified Azure Blob(s).

I have been trying to follow the steps in this document  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/

Answer (score 1):

You need a general purpose Azure Storage Account for the Azure Batch to successfully download the assembly to Pool nodes. You got the error possibly because you use Blog Storage only storage account.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown by your Azure Batch Pool and from the message it seems your VM could have transient connectivity issue so I would suggest either retry the failed slice to see if that goes away. If not, then I would try reboot the Pool VMs or even switch to a new Pool.

Thanks,
Yitao

Comment: This would be better served as a comment than an answer seeing as it's speculation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you deployed a custom pipeline in a zipped file and in the meantime the container name containing that pipeline was renamed.
The specified Azure Blob is the pipeline you deployed.

Comment: Just curious, how did you find that out without any clarification?

Comment: I had the same problem few days ago (the same error)! ADF tries to download custom pipeline zip, but fails instantly because pipeline had been deployed and accepted before the container name was changed. And, after the container name was changed it does not matter for the pipeline because it was already provisioned! (Second case is that pipeline zip name was changed, but that's only possible in Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer app).